# Select another column from rows that match a filter and then delete based on the new selected column in R

Tags: r, filter, data-cleaning

Example dataset

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(11, 12, 11, 12, 13, 11, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15),
       year = c(2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019),
       name = c("Jay", "Rahul", "Jay", "Rahul", "Pierre", "Jay", "Pierre",
                "Shannon", "Rahul", "Shannon", "Zachary"))
```

| ID | year | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2022 | Jay |
| 12 | 2022 | Rahul |
| 11 | 2021 | Jay |
| 12 | 2021 | Rahul |
| 13 | 2021 | Pierre |
| 11 | 2020 | Jay |
| 13 | 2020 | Pierre |
| 14 | 2020 | Shannon |
| 12 | 2019 | Rahul |
| 14 | 2019 | Shannon |
| 15 | 2019 | Zachary |

How would I go about removing every ID that appears in the 2022 column (Jay and Rahul)? Please keep in mind that I'm working with around 9000 rows and around 70 years, so I can't look up names physically. I need to efficiently tell R to look up all the IDs in 2022 and then remove any row that has those IDs.

I've tried to look for this solution but all I find are articles on conditionally removing rows via filter and/or subset and I haven't found a way to make those work for this scenario.

Also, I'm working with the following packages so feel free to use them in your answer - tidyverse, dplyr, janitor, stringr

The output should look like this

| ID | year | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 2021 | Pierre |
| 13 | 2020 | Pierre |
| 14 | 2020 | Shannon |
| 14 | 2019 | Shannon |
| 15 | 2019 | Zachary |

Thank you

Comment: is this what you are looking for? df[!df$ID %in% df[df$year==2022,"ID"],]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple `dplyr` methods:

```
# grouped filter
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!any(year == 2022)) %>%
  ungroup()

# anti-join
df %>%
  filter(year == 2022) %>%
  select(ID) %>%
  anti_join(x = df, y = ., by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df[!df$ID %in% df[df$year==2022,"ID"],]

   ID year    name
5  13 2021  Pierre
7  13 2020  Pierre
8  14 2020 Shannon
10 14 2019 Shannon
11 15 2019 Zachary
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, if(!any(year==2022)) .SD, by = ID]

#   ID year    name
#1: 13 2021  Pierre
#2: 13 2020  Pierre
#3: 14 2020 Shannon
#4: 14 2019 Shannon
#5: 15 2019 Zachary
```

Or here are a couple of base R options:

```
#subset
subset(df, !ID %in% unique(ID[year == 2022]))

#with
df[!with(df, ave(year == 2022, ID, FUN = any)), ]
```